# Select Distinct 2 Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have the following table: `ID1 , ID2, Name, Sex`

In the table there are records with duplicate ID1 but different ID2,name and sex -- Also there are records with duplicate ID2 and different ID1,Name and sex.
Both ID1 and ID2 can have null values but not for same entry.
I need to select non duplicate record for id1 and id2 e.g.

```
id1   id2      name    sex
10     null    jack     M
10     null    tom      M
null   40      jennie   F
null    32     jenie    F
null    32     emma     M
10     null    stevie   M
```

Need a select query to return:

```
id1   id2     name     sex
10     any    any      any (any means it can be either jack,tom,stevie)
null   40     jennie   F
null   32     any      any2 (any2 meaning jeniw or emma)
```

Comment: Are you sure that emma is male?

Comment: I was too occupied to decide emma's sex when i posted the question. Infact, bluefoot provided the soln and also changed emma's sex back to female(what she was suppoed to be to begin with)..good catch Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `EXISTS` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
select t1.id1,
  t1.id2,
  name,
  sex
from yourtable t1
where exists (select *
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.id1 = t2.id1
               or t1.id2 = t2.id2)
group by t1.id1, t1.id2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecf6d/6)

Comment: I m using sql server 2005 which asks for both name and sex to be in group by and this results in all entries in the table. Error: Column 'yourtable.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.: select t1.id1, t1.id2, name, sex from yourtable t1 where exists (select * from yourtable t2 where t1.id1 = t2.id1 or t1.id2 = t2.id2) group by t1.id1, t1.id2....Any Solutions for this?

Comment: Did you try adding them to the group by clause?